# What is best schema design for Base Information?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, oop, database-design

We have at least 50 objects (for example: `city`, `country`, `color`, `personelType`, `organizationType` and so on...) in our application that contains the same properties. These properties contain: `ID`, `Topic`, `Code`, `isActive`

- for these objects that contains the same properties, we create two objects known as `BaseInfo` and `BaseHeader`.
- for design table of this objects, we create one table that known as `Base-Header` and other table that known as `Base-Info`. The relationship of these tables is: https://pasteboard.co/GQeV4Rl.png

Now, developers add new record in `Base-Header` if needed. For example a developer see `Base-Header` and if it has no record in the table for `city` then add one record for city object: `insert into Base-Header (id, topic) values (1, 'city');` or for color: `insert into Base-Header (id, topic) values (2, 'color');`. after this all developers known that value of `headerId` field in city records into `Base-Info` is `1` and can hardcode this id on application for get data of city. Other object that has same status in our application.

With this plan, we don't need to create tables and objects for `city`, `color` and so on that have same properties. All foreign keys of other tables that need city record, they are attached with `Base-Info` table. Is this design of table and object correct?

- consider you have this schema [ https://pasteboard.co/GQnqaT5.png ] and changed to this [ https://pasteboard.co/GQnqiCE.png ]. with this work we remove all objects and tables that have same prop. note. query not changed and is not added any join or where clause. just foreign keys changes to Base_Info. is this complicated?

thanks a lot...

Comment: Can you please share your current schema and requirements ? because currently i am not able to understand your problem.

Comment: Well it certainly sounds confusing and complicated, based on that I'd say it's not a very good solution for a problem I'm not sure I can see.

Comment: @kayaman this pattern designed and we used it we need to understand that is this approach correct or we need to create table per object?

Comment: On the information given it seems like a terrible idea. Create separate tables for each type of thing in your database. On the face of it what you are describing seems extremely simple and typical but you are in danger of over complicating things with a very non-typical solution.

Comment: @sqlvogel thanks for replay, with consideration of your opinion, we have at least 50 to 200 objects that has same property and we must creates table per objects. is it good idea that we create at least 50 table with same property?

Comment: [OTLT and EAV: the two big design mistakes all beginners make](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html)

Comment: @sqlvogel consider you have this schema [ https://pasteboard.co/GQnqaT5.png ] and changed to this [ https://pasteboard.co/GQnqiCE.png ]. with this work we remove all objects and tables that have same prop. note. query not changed and is not added any join or where clause. just foreign keys changes to `Base_Info`. is this complicated?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your actual problem. But I can suggest you one idea to design database for the above problem. See you can make enum of your list of objects (city, country, color, pesonnelType etc.) if they are not varying frequently else you can store all the above objects in single table along with id. and add a column in base-info table to store id of your respective object. So your latest base-info table will have one extra column `object-id`. I think your problem will be resolved in this way..

Comment: thanks for replay. based on your approach, we must remove `Base-Header` table and add Enum class for list of objects. this is good but my question is that, all foreign key of other table attached with `Base-Info` table. is this way correct? or we must create one table per object (for example: `cityTable` map to `city` object)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to go for an [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) type approach here. It's not a good fit for RDBMSes. Not design-wise, not performance-wise and not usability-wise.

If the only purpose of `BaseHeader` is to give a type to the entity, then it's not really necessary. As Lawakush indicated, you could just as well use an `enum` field (if the database supports it, otherwise you can emulate it) instead of a separate table.

If you are going for the EAV model, you have been warned. It may seem great that you can model "anything", but you can end up with a huge pile of unmaintainable garbage, with data being corrupted due to the lack of proper safeguards in the database: foreign keys don't work that well in an EAV model.

Comment: we don't work with EAV model, we have exclusive tables for any entities but we use from top model (commented in question) in LOV's. like LOV's for combo, dropbox or others.

Comment: we don't have any extension like form generator for create table run time, we work with this design in develop time, for map objects that have same prop.

Answer (score -2):

You need to at least 3-6 months analyzing business requirements first. It will become handy once everything comes to place. As I noticed in your statement, it seems it is not being reviewed by business analyst. You need to refer this from the BA's perspective so once compiled and summarized it will became clear in technical perspective doing data warehousing.

Comment: this approach designed with database analysis, just we need to understand that this approach is a correct solution or we need to create table per object? note. these objects have same properties. in our approach, we mapped all objects into one table.

Comment: From that, yes, this approach is correct. It is same as doing a lookup functionality. You may also need to add a column flag, to compare in the target table and source table whether 'I' Inserted, 'U' updated,'Deleted' (For historical record).